# why my google map isn't loading perfectly?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
<h4>Location</h4>
<div class="full-row mt20">
    <?php 
    if(empty($restaurant['Restaurant']['lattitude']))
        $restaurant['Restaurant']['lattitude'] = 0;

    if(empty($restaurant['Restaurant']['longitude']))
        $restaurant['Restaurant']['longitude'] = 0;
    ?>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
    function initialize() {

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $restaurant['Restaurant']['lattitude']; ?>,<?php echo $restaurant['Restaurant']['longitude']; ?>);
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 6,
          center: myLatlng
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);
      var marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:myLatlng});

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
    });


  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
  <div id="googleMap" style="height:250px;"></div>
```

![enter image description here][1]

![enter image description here][2]
Output image links are: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGS3X.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SLRK.png
The above portion is my code and my result. I can't find the error. when I drag the map the another portion of the map will invisible. why this happen?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901520/grey-area-in-google-maps

Comment: [Your code as posted does not exhibit the issue reported](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfx5jdak/2/).  Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

like @KimGyesen said, you must refresh the map using resize.
try this code snippet, may be this help you a little...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        center: myLatlng
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
    });
    setInterval(function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        map.fitBounds();
    }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<body>
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px; height:400px"></div>
</body>
```