# agm-map Angular Google Map Limit Panning and Zooming

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular8, agm-map

I am working with **Angular 8** with **agm-map**. I want to define a limit the map area that user can zoom or pan(drag). without any limitations user **can pan even beyond the north and south bounds** of the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were couple of ways previously handle same problem. One way was listening to **boundsChange** event and if user has pan beyond the limit simply set boundaries back to the area we want. you can find the more details about boudsChange event in [here](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/components/agmmap#boundsChange). 
But there is a very easy way method for this using in built **restriction** attribute. restriction is a **MapRestriction** typed attribute. I just assigned the below value to avoid panning beyond the nort and south boundaries of the map,

```
restriction: {
    latLngBounds:{
      north: 85.0, 
      south: -85.0, 
      west: -180.0, 
      east: 180.0
    },
    strictBounds : true
  }
```

In same way you can define your restrictions using Longitudes and Latitudes in the map.for more details about **restriction** attribute visit [here](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/components/agmmap#restriction).